# Hide PHP password in HTML Link

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, camera, ip

first time posting here, english is not my native language ^^.

I need to display and control a IP camera stream on my website. I try it in the following way:

```
 <?php
 $user = "user";
 $password = "password";

 echo "<img alt='' src='http://cameralink.nl/videostream.cgi?user=
 {$user}&pwd={$password}'>";

 ?>
```

The problem: If I look into the source code, I'll see the username and password in plain text, and that is of course not the intention. Is there a way to change this?

Thnx!

Comment: why are you putting the password in a img src?

Comment: A safer alternative would be to get the file on your server, save it there and then send a normal image link to the browser.

Comment: @madalinivascu, i also need to control the camera, so that is why i need to have the password filled in. I dont want to fill in a password everytime i refresh the page.

Comment: Everytime you access the image via http your password is potentially readable also.

Comment: (That ampersand should be html encoded: `&amp;`)

Comment: Could you not create a PHP script that reads the image in from that URL and just prints out the jpg? Then `<img src... />` to that file. That way the username and password only exist in your PHP file and aren't displayed on the frontend anywhere.

Comment: Any authentication scheme that accepts credentials via the URL is doomed by design. There's literally no way to make this secure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no PHP solution here. An appropriate solution would be to add a form to the webpage that asks for username and password. When that is entered, a javascript would add the `<img>` tag to the page, with the specified username and password appended.

This way, yes the username and password will be in clear text on the browser, but since the user has to already know the credentials, this is not a leak.

You should of course also make sure that the stream is hosted on HTTPS instead since, every request to HTTP is sent in clear text and all observers of your request would be getting to see the credentials as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the safest way to handle it. 
But the shortest way is to encrypt your username and password or generate a hash. so that way you can hide the username and password.